# Hoverable sidebar manu or right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am searching for sidebar manu on right side. I want a hidden sidebar which appears when you scroll on it.
Very similar sidebar to that of https://www.psx.com.pk

Comment: link not working

Comment: @AsAd nAbeel you want to show from left to right hidden menu?

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Please show us what you have tried yourself to create this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: you need put some effort from your side first. Based on the code, we can provide the solution.

Comment: @Kiran Mistry link is working fine but I think because of restriction it could be not working in you country please use vpn if you have.

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar I want a sidebar or right side of my page. Some part of sidebar appearing on right side and when i scroll through that part of sidebar it should move from right to left and shows up completely

Comment: @Carsten Sorry dear I am new here that is why don't know how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

div {
 background: #f4f4f4;
 position: absolute;
 right: -200px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

div:hover {
 right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much thats what I was looking for. Its a good start to work on. 

Comment: @AsAdnAbeel Glad I could help. Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start for you. Change some options and you are good to go.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Toggle Sidebar</button>  
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this helps then click on Accept Checkbox